# How to resolve null DateTime field in Ajax POST?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datetime, object, properties

I've passed in a serialized form in an Ajax POST function to my controller. All the properties are being mapped to the escalation object in the controller's constructor except for `DateTime?` `NextUpdate`  field.

So in order to debug this I checked a number of things below:

> Input field element ID matches name of model property - yes
>
> Other object properties are populated in passed in escalation object -
>   yes
>
> NextUpdate input field is within the createForm form container - yes
>
> DateTime value has been populated in the view - yes

**Question:**

Does anyone know why my DateTime property is null in the escalation object?

- Below is a gist of my setup for context:

DateTimePicker declaration (I use the second input element to pass back the DateTime value):

```
               <form action="" id="createForm" class="form-group has-warning" method="post">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">

                                    <!-- NextUpdateDisplay -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="NextUpdateDisplay">Next Update Due</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <div class='input-group date' id='NextUpdateDisplay'>
                                                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                    <!-- Next Update Hidden Field -->
                                    <div>
                                        <input id="NextUpdate" name="NextUpdate" type="text" hidden disabled="disabled" />
                                    </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Javascript that passes the DateTimePicker value to my NextUpdate hidden input field onChange of the DateTimePicker values:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#NextUpdateDisplay').datetimepicker({

        });
    });

    $("#NextUpdateDisplay").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#NextUpdate').val(moment(e.date).format());
    });
```

Ajax method:

```
$("#dialog-confirm-submit").dialog("open").on("dialogclose", function (event, ui) {
                if ($(this).data("state") == "confirmed") {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@(Url.Action("Index", "CreateEscalation"))",
                        type: 'POST',
                    traditional: true,
                    data: $("#createForm").serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        //todo: use result
                        if (result.Success) {
                            window.location.href = result.redirectUrl;
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#submitStatus').text("Error occurred while processing your request, please try again or contact system administrators");
                            $(this).addClass('alert alert-danger fade in');
                            $('#submitStatus').show();

                        }
                    }
                });

                }
            });
```

Controller post method: (gist)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Escalation escalation)
    {


        //do  controller stuff here..

    }
```

Model property: (gist)

```
public partial class Escalation
{

    public DateTime? NextUpdate { get; set; }

}
```

Contents of escalation object in controller at runtime:

[image]

Comment: What is the actual JSON payload sent to the server?

Comment: @Amy any tip on how I can view the JSON payload?

Comment: Use your browser console tools, the Network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On closer inspection we found out that the model binder only picks up READ-ONLY fields. The hidden input NextUpdate had the following property which prevented it from being picked up:

```
disabled="disabled"
```

Commenting out this setting allowed the model binder to pick up the DateTime field.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that javascript post a string but your controller would like to take an DateTime? type so they're mismatch. Try to access data from the Request, something like:

```
Escalation.NextUpdate = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["NextUpdate"])) ? DateTime.ParseExact(Request["NextUpdate"].Trim(),"MM/dd/yyyy", null) : Escalation.NextUpdate;
```